# Attach debugger to running java command line local process with Intellij?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I did read the similar question on `SO` which points to the documentation on how to attach and debug a remote process.  I have tried this to debug a local process with no luck - I have tried setting up my Remote debug config to point to `localhost` and a `port` I just picked based on that example.

```
java ./myTestProcess -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

It seems `Intellij` is oblivious this and I don't see a menu option to "**Attach To Process**" similar to other debuggers I have used.

Comment: Run - Edit configurations - click on the + icon on the top left - choose "Remote".

Comment: Thanks - That got me a bit further. When I use debugger mode "listen" it seems like this is serving up the debug listener port properly if I Run the Remote configuration, but I still don't see how to attach this to a running process?  Am I telling the running process where to connect to, to allow it to be debugged, or do I tell the Remote configuration which process to debug (by IP and Port)?

Comment: You start your Java application with the debugging options that allow a debugger to connect to it, and then you execute your remote configuration in IntelliJ. Of course, the options you enter in the IntelliJ run configuration must match with the options used when starting the application.

Comment: There are two modes in IntelliJ:
The "listen" - IntelliJ serves as the server and your application is connection to it. For this mode you have to use different command line arguments for your java process (you can find them in runner configuration).
The "attach" - your application serves as the server and IntelliJ is connecting to it. Configuration for your application for this mode is in your question. Your application has to be really a server. It means that it has to run all the time. If your code just quickly run and ends you cannot use this mode.